# Android Studio - Fetching JSON from URL FATAL EXCEPTION

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

So I am having some problems with getting this code to work, I found some of this code online but it won't work. I have tried adjusting some code but no matter what I am doing, the app just crashes with an error. I have been trying to get this to work for a few days now with hours of googling and watching YouTube tutorials and I cannot seem to get this to work.

Can someone shed some light on what I am doing wrong here?

**CODE:**

```
public class fetchJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL("www.link.to.json");
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET"); //Your method here
            urlConnection.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            if (inputStream == null) {
                return null;
            }
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                buffer.append(line + "\n");

            if (buffer.length() == 0)
                return null;

            return buffer.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IO Exception", e);
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        if(response != null) {
            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                json = new JSONObject(response);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            JSONObject jsonResponse = null;
            try {
                jsonResponse = json.getJSONObject("Question1");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            MainActivity.jsonPrint.setText((CharSequence) jsonResponse);
        }
    }
}
```

**ERROR:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: uk.co.jrtevents.fetchjsonfromurltest, PID: 4019
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:318)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke a virtual method on a null object reference
        at uk.co.jrtevents.fetchjsonfromurltest.fetchJSON.doInBackground(fetchJSON.java:31)
        at uk.co.jrtevents.fetchjsonfromurltest.fetchJSON.doInBackground(fetchJSON.java:18)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
```

**LINE 31:**
`urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");`

Comment: What is line 31 of `fetchJSON.java`?

Comment: Updated the question to reflect your request, it is: ```urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
```

You never assign a value to `urlConnection`, and so it is `null`.

You would need to add:

```
urlConnection = url.openConnection();
```

before trying to use `urlConnection`.

`URL` and `HttpURLConnection` are *very* old, and very few developers use them anymore. You may have better luck using more modern HTTP client APIs, such as [OkHttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp).